# Fix SVG height but allow horizontal scaling

Tags: css, svg, resize

I have an SVG image where I need keep a consistent height but allow it to grow horizontally with the view window. I've looked into the [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute but cannot get it to do anything. I have a feeling there are other issues with my SVG attributes that are preventing this, but I'm very new to SVG and have yet to figure out what is causing the issue and/or conflict. I've also tried multiple different settings with the CSS with no success.

https://jsfiddle.net/cdsLb0wd/2/

```css
.scoop__wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 674px;
  //height: 382px;
  //width: 100%;
}

.combined-shape__scoop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="scoop__wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="392" viewBox="0 0 1440 392">
        <defs>
            <path id="b" d="M1440 .826V620H0V.826v22.826C241.31 82.55 481.31 112 720 112s478.69-29.45 720-88.348V.826z"/>
            <filter id="a" width="106.9%" height="116%" x="-3.4%" y="-8.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <feOffset dy="-3" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
                <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/>
                <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0"/>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-1 9)">
            <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b"/>
            <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#b"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Could you please describe what visual result you want to achieve? Currently, you are placing a black-hued drop-shadow on top of a black background - that does not make much sense, does it? And what element do you want to resize?

Comment: @ccprog: the black background was just to make the white svg visible, don't worry about the shadow. The desired result is the svg at the bottom of view, and keeping a constant height while the width is scalable with the window

Comment: Well, then set attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` on the svg.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what effect you are after, but perhaps

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

gives the effect you want?

```css
.scoop__wrapper {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="scoop__wrapper">
<svg width="100%" height="392" viewBox="0 0 1440 392" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
        <path id="b" d="M1440 .826V620H0V.826v22.826C241.31 82.55 481.31 112 720 112s478.69-29.45 720-88.348V.826z"/>
        <filter id="a" width="106.9%" height="116%" x="-3.4%" y="-8.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset dy="-3" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-1 9)">
        <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b"/>
        <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#b"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cdsLb0wd/3/

Or perhaps you wanted the aspect ratio of the SVG to stay the same, and the SVG occupies the whole width. Then we should just view a portion of it based on the width.  In which case, you should use:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
```

```css
.scoop__wrapper {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="scoop__wrapper">
<svg width="100%" height="392" viewBox="0 0 1440 392" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
    <defs>
        <path id="b" d="M1440 .826V620H0V.826v22.826C241.31 82.55 481.31 112 720 112s478.69-29.45 720-88.348V.826z"/>
        <filter id="a" width="106.9%" height="116%" x="-3.4%" y="-8.5%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feOffset dy="-3" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/>
            <feGaussianBlur in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" stdDeviation="16"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="shadowBlurOuter1" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 0"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-1 9)">
        <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b"/>
        <use fill="#FFF" xlink:href="#b"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cdsLb0wd/4/

Comment: preserve aspect ratio is exactly what I was looking for